# .NET: Inject Data into Input-Buffer of Process

Tags: .net, input, buffer, stdin

I need to automate an command line application. It asks the user to enter a password. All my approches to send the password via STDIN failed. Now I am trying to do this with an wrapper-programm using .NET.

I am starting the application creating a new process, setting the `StartInfo`-properties and then start the process:

```
Dim app_path As String
Dim app_args As String
Dim myProcess As Process = New Process()
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = app_path
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = app_args
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.Start()
```

I did try to use the `StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput` Property but with no success.

Now I came accross the `WriteConsoleInput` function from the `kernel32.dll` that I included like this:

```
Declare Function WriteConsoleInput Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WriteConsoleInputA" (ByVal hConsoleInput As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nNumberOfCharsToWrite As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfCharsWritten As Integer) As Boolean
```

I can get the handle of the process via the `myProcess.Handle` property. But sending input to the input-buffer using this way was also not possible.

I found those questions but they did not help:

- How do I write ‘PAGE DOWN’ into the console input buffer? (1475353)
- Java - passing input into external C/C++ application (1421273)
- Controlling a Windows Console App w/ stdin pipe (723424)

Using StraceNtX.exe I got this output for the moment the app is waiting for input:

```
[T4024] GetConsoleMode(f, 12d35c, 12d3af, 77bff894, ...) = 1
[T4024] SetConsoleMode(f, 0, 12d3af, 77bff894, ...) = 1
[T4024] ReadConsoleInputA(f, 12d348, 1, 12d360, ...) = 1
```

Can anyone tell me, what else to try or how to do the above the right way?
Thanks!

---

Based on Tim Robinsons answere I've got this code now, but it does not work:

```
myProcess = New Process()
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = app_path
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = app_args
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.Start()
' Wait for process requesting passwort input
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
Dim len As Integer
len = 0
Dim handle As Integer
handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
WriteConsoleInput(handle, "Test", 4, len)
```

My programm is an commandline application that should act as an wrapper.

The input is send but in a way that it is not typed into the password field but that below the password field a new promt is shown (without even showing the input).

Tim, can you give me an example?

Comment: What's the app that needs the password? There may be an easier way than this.

Comment: It is the Cisco Certificate Manager Console Application cisco_cert_mgr.exe
But I did search already for any different solution but there seems to be none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my late reply, been very busy.

Here is an full code example, stripped down from my code. I hope I did not delete something crucial.

```
Private Sub runWaitInput(ByVal exe As String, ByVal parameter As String, ByVal trigger As String, ByVal input As String)
    ' runs an process, waits for a certain string in stdout and then enters text '
    Dim proc As Process
    Dim stdOut As StreamReader
    Dim ch As Int32
    Dim buffer As String = ""
    Dim InputRecords(0) As KeyEventStruct

    ' create process '
    proc = New Process()
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = exe
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = parameter
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.Start()

    ' redirect stdOut '
    stdOut = proc.StandardOutput
    While Not proc.HasExited
        ' read character '
        ch = stdOut.Read()
        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(ch))
        buffer = buffer & Convert.ToChar(ch)
        ' read output and check for trigger-text '
        If buffer.LastIndexOf(trigger) <> -1 Then
            buffer = ""
            InputRecords(0) = New KeyEventStruct
            InputRecords = generateInputRecord(input & Convert.ToChar(13))
            WriteConsoleInput(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, InputRecords, InputRecords.Count(), New Integer)
        End If
    End While
    Console.Write(stdOut.ReadToEnd())
End Sub

Function generateInputRecord(ByVal str As String) As KeyEventStruct()
    Dim ret(str.Count() - 1) As KeyEventStruct
    For i = 0 To str.Count - 1 Step 1
        With ret(i)
            .EventType = 1
            .bKeyDown = True
            .uChar.AsciiChar = Convert.ToInt32(str(i))
            .dwControlKeyState = 0
            .wRepeatCount = 1
            .wVirtualKeyCode = 0
            .wVirtualScanCode = 0
        End With
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

It uses the following module:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module ConsoleUtils

    <Flags()> Public Enum ControlKeyState As Integer
        RightAltPressed = &H1
        LeftAltPressed = &H2
        RightCtrlPressed = &H4
        LeftCtrlPressed = &H8
        ShiftPressed = &H10
        NumLockOn = &H20
        ScrollLockOn = &H40
        CapsLockOn = &H80
        EnhancedKey = &H100
    End Enum

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)> Public Structure CHAR_UNION
        <FieldOffset(0)> Public UnicodeChar As Short
        <FieldOffset(0)> Public AsciiChar As Byte
    End Structure

    <DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint:="WriteConsoleInputA", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, ThrowOnUnmappablechar:=True)> _
        Public Function WriteConsoleInput( _
            ByVal hConsoleInput As IntPtr, _
            ByVal lpBuffer() As KeyEventStruct, _
            ByVal nLength As Integer, _
            ByRef lpNumberOfEventsWritten As Integer _
        ) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetStdHandle", SetLastError:=False, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
        Public Function GetStdHandle( _
            ByVal nStdHandle As Integer _
        ) As Integer
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure KeyEventStruct
        Public EventType As Short
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Public bKeyDown As Boolean
        Public wRepeatCount As Short
        Public wVirtualKeyCode As Short
        Public wVirtualScanCode As Short
        Public uChar As CHAR_UNION
        Public dwControlKeyState As ControlKeyState
    End Structure

    Public ReadOnly STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE As IntPtr = New IntPtr(GetStdHandle(-11))
    Public ReadOnly STD_INPUT_HANDLE As IntPtr = New IntPtr(GetStdHandle(-10))
    Public ReadOnly STD_ERROR_HANDLE As IntPtr = New IntPtr(GetStdHandle(-12))

End Module
```

With this function you can start the process and wait for a line of output (i.e. "password:"). Then the function will enter the provided text followed by an return.

I hope this helps!

Regards
sc911

Answer (score 0):

`WriteConsoleInput` expects a console handle, not a process handle. Your problem is how to get hold of this console handle.

If your process is a console app, and you don't redirect anything when starting the child process, then the child process will be attached to your own process's console. In which case, you may be able to:

1. Start the child process with redirection turned off
2. Call `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` to get hold of your own console handle
3. Pass that console handle to `WriteConsoleInput`

If you have a GUI app you can assign yourself a console using `AllocConsole`.

**Edit:** I didn't notice at first, but that's not the right definition for `WriteConsoleInput`. It takes an array of `INPUT_RECORD`, not a string. My own experiment with runas.exe works OK once I copied [the function prototype from pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WriteConsoleInput.html).

Comment: I did a test on that (see change above), but it does not work. Can you give me an example?

Comment: It sounds like it behaves similarly to runas.exe; I'll hack together a test using that.

Comment: @sc911, see my edit to the answer - your declaration for WriteConsoleInput is wrong

Comment: Tim, you're the man! Using the info from your link and the ConsoleUtils from here [http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/372364-unblock-console-readline-separate-thread] (change the lpNumberOfEventsWritten-Parameter to ByRef) did the trick! Thanks a lot!