# How to remote control a cmd.exe process in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, cmd, kernel32

I'm really stuck with a problem (for 7 days now) and before I go crazy I thought I'll just ask for advice.

Want I want to do is basically to start and remote control a cmd.exe process. However the StandardInput and StandardOutput streams don't do the job, since they aren't triggered by commands like "mysql" which wait for a user input.

So all I want is to read the content of the cmd.exe console and write to it. However the write method should be able to fire a new command.

I tried a lot and I'm quite sure the kernel32.dll will do the trick:

- ReadConsoleOutput()
- WriteConsoleInput()
- GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()
- SetConsoleCursorPosition()

Of course I already have some stuff working, but I'm absolutly not sure whether or not I took the right road. Therefore I won't post any code since it would probably just confuse you.

It would be awesome if someone could point me to a working demo or tutorial or something like that. Even if it's C++ or C - would be better than nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Mewes Kochheim

PS: Please don't post just a link to pinvoke or MSDN, what I need is little bit more complex. And it seems like I don't have enough winapi experience to get there on my own :/

Edit: I've to try out some of the new ideas I got based on the links you guys posted. I'll will be back and post what I figured out. Thanks for the help guys...

Comment: what do you mean by "invisible" ? in the TaskManager ? On the screen ?

Comment: On the screen, but hiding the window is actually not really a problem :) If it's invisible in the Task Manager that would be okay too but it's not a requirement. I edited the queytion to clarify that point. "Want I want to do is basically to start and remote control a cmd.exe process."

Comment: IF you already know about the kernel32.dll console API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) what exactly do you need ?

Comment: A working example. I have all the information I need, but obviously not the skills to get it right. I'm into Java web development for a living and WinAPI programming is quite new to me.

Comment: check my answer - 3 links to different samples (not very specific though)...

Comment: The basic example I want would be: Starting a cmd.exe process, reading it's content, starting mysql.exe in it, reading the consolebuffer of the cmd.exe process, writing something like "use mytable"+ENTER+"drop table mytable"+ENTER, and reading the output again.

Comment: then check my answer below - there are no mysql samples in those links, but enough to give a good start

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://controllingtheinter.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=116&t=366) you find several examples regarding "remote control of command prompt"...

another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859323/net-inject-data-into-input-buffer-of-process/2227695#2227695) (.NET this time from stackoverflow)...

and [something](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/08/25/stuffing-the-console-keyboard-buffer.aspx) from visualstudio magazine...

Comment: I already tried the examples from link 1 and 2 without much success. I'll look into link 3 this evening. But basically examples like that are what made the last couple of days a hell :)

Comment: to me they look fine... as I wrote above: every program you want to control with this methos has its own "quirks" so it is some trial&error when you really want to implement it this way...

Comment: btw: mysql takes a textfile as input - perhaps this could help with your goal... see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html

Comment: MySQL was just an example. And since I just want communicate with the cmd, it shouldn't matter what kind of application is running in it, since the cmd should handle that. That's why I want to remote control the cmd process and won't just start the application itself.

Comment: I don't know how much experience you have it is for example absolutely possible that MySQL (or anything else) is implemented in such a way that it circumvents STDIN (for whatever reason, be it security or anything else)... in such a case command couldn't "handle" what you expect...

Comment: But in the end every console application has to write to and read from the console buffer. That's why I want access the console buffer directly. If the cmd.exe can print it, I should be able to grab it (which actually works quite easy), and if the keyboard can input stuff to the cmd.exe so should I be able to do.

Comment: it is not true that every console app has to write and read from the console buffer - nearly all will write so grabbing shouldn't be a problem usually, but some (a minority!) will read keystrokes from a "lower level" and ignore the console buffer - then you would have to resort to that level to input something into that app...

Comment: Okay in that case I will ignore those cases for know. Do you an example so I know how to test those cases?

Comment: I don't have any lists or so esp. since the behaviour can even be different in different versions of the same app... that's why I wrote there is some trial&error in getting whatever you want to get when using this approach...