# how to send command to cmd with c#

Tags: c#, android

I try to develop c# app to install apk to android phone with adb shell but I'm beginner for both. I cant send command to cmd.

```
   void getDevices()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe");

        p = Process.Start(startInfo);

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd " + @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\adb\");
       // String output  = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();





    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options:

1. Pass the commands into `cmd.exe` when you start it
2. Send the commands to `cmd.exe` after it has started
3. Writing a batch file or PowerShell script

**Pass the commands into `cmd.exe` when you start it**

To pass commands to `cmd.exe` you can use the `-k` or `-c` parameters of `cmd.exe`.

For example, this will start `cmd.exe`, display the logged on user and then terminate the `cmd.exe` process:

```
cmd.exe /c "whoami"
```

Look at [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) or Google for more examples.

**Send the commands to `cmd.exe` after it has started**

The alternative is to first start `cmd.exe` and later send commands to it. There are quite a few questions about that around already, but there generally seem two approaches:

1. Send one key at a time, e.g. [How can I send keypresses to a running process object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686865/how-can-i-send-keypresses-to-a-running-process-object)
2. Send data to the input buffer of the process, e.g. [.NET: Inject Data into Input-Buffer of Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859323/net-inject-data-into-input-buffer-of-process)

I'm not sure if they'll work with `cmd.exe`.

**Writing a batch file or PowerShell script**

The more common approach to automating `cmd.exe` is to write a batch file or PowerShell script. You may also want to consider these options.

Comment: Your link for "Send data to the input buffer of the process" has a solution of Visual Basic. Anything in C#?

Comment: If you find it difficult to convert the code manually, google for a VB.NET to C# conversion tool.

Comment: Ah, so you're not answer my question directly, either.